Get hierarchy context in a Strawberry custom field resolver
TL;DR
I need to access information from the "parent" of an object who's field I'm calculating in a custom resolver, but that information does not seem to be available during the resolver's execution.

Assuming I have 2 objects that have a many-to-many relation, describing which clients accessed which resources, something like (simplified example) -
// graphql query
{
  consumers {
    node {
      id
      resources {
        node {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

that might return something like (indicating that 2 consumers accessed the same single resource)
{
  "data": {
    "consumer": {
      "node": [
        {
          "id": "consumer1",
          "resource": {
            "node": [{ "id": "resource1" }]
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "consumer2",
          "resource": {
            "node": [{ "id": "resource1" }]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

And assuming I have a DB table that looks something like this, which maps the last interaction of each consumer-resource pair.



consumer_id
resource_id
last_accessed




consumer1
resource1
08/05/2022


consumer2
resource1
11/03/2024



I now want to create a custom resolver to add a lastAccesed field to the resource object, which will be calculated by fetching the last_accessed field from the above table.
I started to write a custom resolver that looks something like this -
def resolve(parent: Any, info: Info):
    # `parent` here is the resource object
    resource_id = getattr(parent, 'id', None)
    consumer_id = # ??? this is what I need to somehow get
    
    # ... get `last_accessed` from DB by resource_id + consumer_id

But I can't figure out how to get the ID of the consumer I'm "currently under" in the calculation. For the example query above, my resolver will get called twice, both with the same resource - which is fine - but there is no info in the parent or context that I can use to figure out under which consumer I am.
I can use the parent parameter to access the list of all consumers that the resource is linked to, but the list will include both consumers in both invocations of the resolver, so this is not helpful.

How do your resolvers for consumers and its subobject node work?

Why node instead of letting consumers be a list directly? Are there more fields than node in consumers?

In the parent class, where you have the ID, implement the field as a method:
@strawberry.type
class Consumer:
    id: str

    @strawberry.field
    def resources(self) -> ResourceHolder:
        return ResourceHolder(id=self.id)

Here you can implement ResourceHolder like this:
@strawberry.type
class ResourceHolder:
    id: strawberry.Private[str]

    @strawberry.field
    def node(self) -> typing.List[Resource]:
        match self.id:
            case "consumer1":
                return [Resource(id="resource1")]
            case "consumer2":
                return [Resource(id="resource1")]
            case _:
                return []

My full "solution":
import typing
import strawberry

@strawberry.type
class Resource:
    id: str = strawberry.field()

@strawberry.type
class ResourceHolder:
    id: strawberry.Private[str]

    @strawberry.field
    def node(self) -> typing.List[Resource]:
        match self.id:
            case "consumer1":
                return [Resource(id="resource1")]
            case "consumer2":
                return [Resource(id="resource1")]
            case _:
                return []

@strawberry.type
class Consumer:
    id: str

    @strawberry.field
    def resources(self) -> ResourceHolder:
        return ResourceHolder(id=self.id)


@strawberry.type
class ConsumersHolder:
    @strawberry.field
    def node(self) -> typing.List[Consumer]:
        return [
            Consumer(id="consumer1"),
            Consumer(id="consumer2")
        ]


@strawberry.type
class Query:
    @strawberry.field
    def consumers() -> ConsumersHolder:
        return ConsumersHolder()


schema = strawberry.Schema(query=Query)

